# How do I get the value of an dictionary for Django?

Tags: python, django

I am using aggregate to average out some values in a table. It returns as:
[image]

How would I display 3.5 in the template? I am passing rating as a dictionary to the template.

Comment: You subscript: `rating['revieww_content_rating__avg']`.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *subscript*, so:

```
rating['review_content__rating__avg']
```

It might however make sense to pass the expression in the [**`.aggregate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) call to make the key shorter, and also make it more robust for fieldname changes: in that case you only need to change the expression.

For example:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

result = MyModel.objects.aggregate(
    avg_review=Avg('review_content__rating')
)['avg_review']  # 3.5
```

Here we thus give the aggregate the name `avg_review`. For more complex aggregates, it is even *mandatory* to give a name yourself.